# Oxygen XML editor webhelp (HTML) output tags issue in Notepad++

Tags: css, xml, tags, listitem, oxygenxml

I am using Oxygen XML Editor tool for creating HTML output.
When I create one HTML output and open its index file in the notepad++, I see tags like dl, dt, and dd instead of tags like ul and li.
Can anyone tell me the issue here?
Can we customize some parameters during the transformation process, so that we get only the ul and li tags instead of dl, dt, and dd tags.

Take a look at the image for the issue: [Tags issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MsB7.png)

Please let me know if there is any solution out there to try.

Thanks,

gaurav

I am expecting to get ul, and li tags instead of dl, dt and dd tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the DITA XML topics tags like “ol” and “ul” are used, the html equivalent of the topic will contain similar tags. If that does not happen you may have some extra publishing customizations or publishing plugins which alter the generated html content.

Comment: Hello Radu, Thanks for your suggestions.                                                                    
After a few trials and errors, I have found the solution. During transformation,  click parameters and in toc.list.type parameter, change the value to ul or ol instead of dl. It will display the changed tags (ul or ol instead of dl/dd/dt) in the notepad++ output.

Comment: With pleasure. As far as I know there is no "toc.list.type" parameter neither in the DITA Open Toolkit nor in the custom publishing plugins Oxygen adds to it. So I think this specific parameter pertains to a certain publishing customization you have.

Comment: Actually I was talking about Docbook4 framework not DITA. I forgot to mention that in the beginning.